# SharePoint Online : Content types from hub are not publishing to all site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, pnp-powershell, content-type-hub

I have two questions:

1. we are provisioning around 45,000 site collections (Modern Team site with no office 365 group), majority of site collections are getting content types inherited from content type hub but some are not. We waited for more than 4 days now. We tried republishing the content types in hub and also for each subscribed site collection, update the "metadatatimestamp" property using pnp cmdlet -

Set-PnPPropertyBagValue -Key "metadatatimestamp" -Value " "

But still content types are not getting published for around 5000 site collections. Any ideas / suggestion please to solve this issue? I read a post where Microsoft has backend refresh button which eventually pushes for these sticky ones? Is it worth to raise a service request now?

2. All subscribed site collections have Document ID service enabled, but in libraries am not able to find Document ID columns (_dlc_DocIdUrl) to add in library views. I enabled Document ID service in content typ hub site as well republished the content types and also ran the above PnP cmdlet. Still am not able to add "Document ID" column in library views (it is not at all visible), tried in UI and also in PowerShell.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please wait, you might not immediately see document IDs associated with your documents.**

Although you have activated the Document ID service feature , the process of assigning ID's to documents is completed by an automated timer job in SharePoint Online which is out of our control!

[image: wait]

You could refer to the floowing articles to get more information:

- [Enable and configure unique Document IDs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984)
- [SPO CONTENT TYPE HUB](https://joannecklein.com/2016/09/16/spo-content-type-hub/)
- [Publish a content type from a content publishing hub](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/publish-a-content-type-from-a-content-publishing-hub-58081155-118d-4e7a-9cc5-d43b5dbb7d02?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)